# Using Android Studio click Run, the new code does not take effect

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Using Android Studio, and click `Run`, the new code does not take effect, always need to `clean` and `Sync gradle`, than the new code will take effect, how is it?

Comment: This started happening for me on the new upgrade (whether or not I am using instant run).